# Swift Extension computed variable not read correctly until declared in protocol

Tags: swift, protocols, extension-methods, protocol-extension, protocol-oriented

I have a protocol extension which declares and assigns a static computed variable:

```
protocol DataType {
    
}
extension DataType {
    static var mocks: [Self] { [] }
}
```

Then I have another protocol named Provider which has an `associatedtype` requirement of the DataType protocol and an extension:

```
protocol Provider {
    associatedtype Data: DataType
}

extension Provider {
    static var mock: [Data] {
        Data.mocks
    }
}
```

I then create the following types that conform to DataType and Provider:

```
struct Car: DataType {
    var name: String
    
    static var mocks: [Car] {
        [.init(name: "Nissan"), .init(name: "Toyota")]
    }
}

struct CarProvider: Provider {
    typealias Data = Car
}

print(CarProvider.mock)
```

When I print this out (an empty array `[]`), the `CarProvider` static variable `mock` prints out the default value of the `mocks` variable of DataType - even when `Car` has an assigned array value for `mocks` inside its struct definition

However, as soon as I declare the `mocks` property inside the `DataType` protocol as a requirement, then the `mocks` value of `Car` is correctly read (printing the correct values: `[__lldb_expr_93.Car(name: "Nissan"), __lldb_expr_93.Car(name: "Toyota")]`):

```
protocol DataType {
    static var mocks: [Self] { get }
}
```

Why is the property definition required in the Protocol definition in the first place? Shouldn't the extension value be sufficient? And since the `Car` struct is assigning its own value to the `mocks` variable, shouldn't that be read instead of the default extension value?

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks for your note. this is just for example purposes, my code doesn't actually look like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is the property definition required in the Protocol definition in
> the first place? Shouldn't the extension value be sufficient?

No. An implementation in a protocol extension can only be considered a true *default implementation*, if there is some way for it to be overridden in scope. Without having the requirement in the protocol, Swift has no reason or mechanism to look beyond an extension, because there's nothing else that will match, semantically.

```swift
protocol DataType { }

extension DataType {
  static var mocks: [Self] { [] }
}

func mocks<Data: DataType>(_: Data.Type) -> [Data] {
  Data.mocks // This *is* the extension. That is the only truth.
}
```

```swift
protocol DataType {
  static var mocks: [Self] { get }
}

extension DataType {
  static var mocks: [Self] { [] }
}

func mocks<Data: DataType>(_: Data.Type) -> [Data] {
  Data.mocks // Now, we can dispatch to a concrete `Data` type!
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is really helpful +1